# Vertex AI Custom Container deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a simple application that have PyTorch model for predicting emotions in the text. The model get's downloaded inside the container when it starts to work.
Unfortunately the deployment in vertex ai fails everytime with the message:

```
Failed to deploy model "emotion_recognition" to endpoint "emotions" due to the error: Error: model server never became ready. Please validate that your model file or container configuration are valid.
```

[image]

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8-slim

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /usr/src/emotions
COPY ./schemas/ /emotions/schemas
COPY ./main.py /emotions
COPY ./utils.py /emotions

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST "0.0.0.0"

WORKDIR /emotions

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app"]
```

Here's my main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,Request
from utils import get_emotion
from schemas.schema import Prediction, Predictions, Response

app = FastAPI(title="People Analytics")

@app.get("/isalive")
async def health():
    message="The Endpoint is running successfully"
    status="Ok"
    code = 200
    response = Response(message=message,status=status,code=code)
    return response

@app.post("/predict",
            response_model=Predictions,
            response_model_exclude_unset=True)

async def predict_emotions(request: Request):

    body = await request.json()
    print(body)
    instances = body["instances"]
    print(instances)
    print(type(instances))
    instances = [x['text'] for x in instances]
    print(instances)

    outputs = []

    for text in instances:
       emotion = get_emotion(text)
       outputs.append(Prediction(emotion=emotion))

    return Predictions(predictions=outputs)
```

I cannot see the cause of error in cloud logging so I am curious about the reason. Please check if my health/predict routes are correct for vertex ai or there's something else I have to change.

Comment: When and how are you loading your pytorch model? I've seen quite a few examples here lately where models are being loaded on import, and if that takes a while (if the model is large and fetched over network) the FastAPI app doesn't start running until the hosting provider thinks it's too late and shuts it down.

Comment: The Model gets downloaded when container start running. As it's a transformers model so the app downloads the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend that when deploying an endpoint you should [enable](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-prediction-logging) the use of logs so that you will get more meaningful information from logs.

**This issue could be due to different reasons:**

1. Make sure that the [container configuration](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-prediction-logging) port is using port 8080 or not.Vertex AI sends liveness checks, health checks, and prediction requests to this port on the container. Your container's HTTP server must listen for requests on this port.
2. Make sure that  you have the required permissions.For this you can
   follow this [gcp documention](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control) and also validate that the account you
   are using has enough permissions to read your project's GCS bucket
3. Vertex AI has some [quota limits](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/quotas) to verify this you can also
   follow this [gcp documention](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota).
4. As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/use-custom-container), it should select the default Prediction and health route if you did not specify the path.

If any of the suggestions above work, it’s a requirement to contact GCP Support by creating a support case to [fix it](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub). It’s impossible for the community to troubleshoot it without using internal GCP resources

Comment: How do I see the ERROR details in the cloud logging? The logs doesn't say anything about the ERROR whether it's a permission issue, the configuration issue or what else. Also, the severity of logs (as indicated in the logging screenshot) is always ERROR. Can I see exactly what's going wrong to correct it accordingly?

Comment: @AhmadCoachendo I updated my answer by providing the link about gcp enable cloud logging documentation.Even after that if you cannot find the reason for the error I would recommend you raise a ticket with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support). If not, create a thread in Google’s Issue Tracker using this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659). You can also STAR the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).